# Add a div at end of the form so that i can display data over there

Tags: 7, forms

This is my code..

```
function mymodule_menu()
{
$items = array();

  $items['mymodules/page'] = array(
    'title' => t('my module settings'),
    'description' => t('change values here'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_page'),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
   );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_page()
{
$form = array();

$brandarray = array('nokia','siemes');
 $form['mymodule_brand'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Brand'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('mymodule_brand', 'nokia'),
    '#options' => $brandarray,
    '#description' => t('Change this.'),
  );
 $form['div_tag'] = array('#type' => 'markup', '#value' => '<div id="div-id-1">content comes here</div>'); 
 return system_settings_form($form);

}
```

I just want to do like this. After the form is displayed i just want to add a div so that i can use it for my dynamic data which comes after select is changed. How do i do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$form['my_markup'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<p>Lorem ipsum</p>'
);
```

Check the documentation at
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html#markup